Get Daily High & Low of BTC on Google Sheet in Tabular Format
I need to populate by Google Sheet with Daily High & Low prices of USD-BTC.
I have a date column "A1". I need the High and Low for "A" to be populated in Col "B1" & "C1"
Tried =iferror(IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A1)>6,WEEKDAY(A1)=1), "", INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("BTCUSD", "high", A1-1), 2, 2)),"")
Doesnt fetch.
Which Google Function will do this for me?
